# React Native run ios failed only on terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, compiler-errors

I getting an error of

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/naehyungkim/Documents/GitHub/HappyTooCustomerApp1.0_FrontEnd/ios/Dummy.swift
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/naehyungkim/Documents/GitHub/HappyTooCustomerApp1.0_FrontEnd/ios/Fix.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(3 failures)
```

it cam be compiled well on xcode but I can't compile on terminal.
I tried

- delete node_moduels and re-install
- delete derived_folder in xcode
- delete all the project and re-download from github

I recently changed my pc to IMac and having a trouble with this error.
all the details are:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 128.59 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.6.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.11 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.20.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2021.08.02.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 12.5.1/12E507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_292 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^5.0.1-alpha.2 => 5.0.1-alpha.2 
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.64.1 => 0.64.1 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Any helps would be appreciate.
Thank you

full error link is

https://docs.google.com/document/d/166-4Khubzjlzahqgd6c0lpip1M5woHE7PgCQ1hidfhA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Which version of xcode you use? it seems that the issue liase on native side, instead of react native. Is there any other error logs you could provide?

Comment: @TommyLeong I am using xcode 12.5.1

Comment: @TommyLeong error details https://docs.google.com/document/d/166-4Khubzjlzahqgd6c0lpip1M5woHE7PgCQ1hidfhA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems to have a lot of module errors in your build. Try removing your `.xcworkspace` and `Pods` folder. Re-install pod by running `pod install`, then run your project `.xcworkspace` again

Comment: @TommyLeong I tried that but still getting same errors

Comment: Check both your ios version set in Podfile `platform: ios, 11.0` and Xcode's ios target version `iOS 11.0`  .... it should be the same

Comment: Check out to some [solutions raised here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503)